# Latex beamer custom logo

Tags: beamer, png, logos, convert

How do i convert a black and white logo of mine

[image: My logo]

To have the effect as down below?

[image: intended logo]

Comment: The logo is used in one of beamer latex template. I’m planning to use my own logo instead.

Answer (score 3):

The `transparent` package seems to provide what you are looking for.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{transparent}
\begin{document}
    {\transparent{0.1}\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{logo.png}}
\end{document}
```

Adjust the value `0.1` as you see fit.

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

As `beamer` is using `pgf` internally anyway, you could simply change the pgf fill opacity for the logo:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\logo{%
    \pgfsetfillopacity{0.2}
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{pZlTl}
    \pgfsetfillopacity{1}   
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]